# R shiny: passing input variables to java script

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio

I'm fairly new to R shiny and I'm trying to build an app that display a table based on user's input.  I'm trying to write a java-script to allow user to bold the content in the first column.

Currently, my java script has to manually specifies the variable that should be bolded (the part in bold below), and I want to make this dynamic based on user's input. For example, if user put in "chevrolet" in the textbox, those who are "chevrolet" in the first column should changed to bold. I tried to do "var x = input$var", but it seems like the variable is not passing to the java script...  Can someone shed some light on how I can make this to work?

server.R:
library(shiny)

```
  library(ggplot2)

  shinyServer(function(input, output) {

    # Filter data based on selections
    output$table <- renderDataTable({
      data <- mpg
      data
    }
    ,
      options = list(bSort = 0,    
                     bFilter=0,   
                     bAutoWidth=0, 

                     **fnRowCallback = I(
                       'function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {
                          for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
                          *var x = "audi";*
                              if (aData[0] == x)
                              $("td:eq(0)", nRow).css("font-weight", "bold");
                          }
                   }'
                     )**

      ) 
  )
  })
```

ui.R:

```
  library(ggplot2)

  shinyUI(
    fluidPage(
      titlePanel("Basic DataTable"),

      fluidRow(
        column(4, 
               textInput("var", label = h3("Variable to bold"), value = "audi")
        )     
      ),
      fluidRow(
        dataTableOutput(outputId="table")
      )    
    )  
  )
```

Thanks so much in advance!